# External Javascript File with Script tags

Tags: javascript, html, icanhaz.js

I am using a javascript templating framework called ICanHazjs.com.

My questions is can I include  tags inside of a external javascript file, and if so is there any downsides / compatibility issues with this?

And if I can't what can I attach that will let me add  tags.

Comment: I want my external JS file to be able to have script blocks inside of it.  I.E.  <script id="locationTemplate" type="text/html"></scrip>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICanHaz supports adding templates at runtime with `addTemplate`.  It's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean can you include HTML markup inside the Javascript file, no that will not work.  The script will be parsed strictly as Javascript.

However, the included Javascript can *create* HTML markup and add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

if you are only looking for scripts to append you can try this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.id = 'foo_id';
script.src = 'myjs.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

otherwise you might try

```
document.write('<h1>this is pretty ugly in here</h1>');
```

for document.write there are some common pitfalls :)